# How should I create my HTML5 Manifest using Zend Framework?

Tags: php, zend-framework, html

I don't think that Zend Framework has any support for the generation of [HTML5 Manifest files](http://diveintohtml5.info/offline.html). How should I go about creating one? I'm assuming I should create a specialized controller to generate it.

Comment: As far as I can tell these are just plain text files, so could you not just create it using a text editor?

Comment: Well, it must be served with a special MIME type. But other than that, yes it's a text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe a [plugin](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.plugins.html) is more what you need, although you'll still need to have some way to register all your static content but you can use the script and style view helpers to extract some of that information.